# 2010s animated movie with father who creates portal and gets captured by giants. His family go to rescue him

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, hard-sci-fi

This movie's texture is animated realistic 3D CGI, I watched it around 2012-2013.

The movie is about a father, who is obviously some kind of scientist with a lab situated in a city in space who does research to create a portal to a distant planet or dimension in a high tech future, I mean he already lives in an era where space travel and robots are possible. He succeeds but gets captured there by a race of blue giants/trolls.

His son and his mom or sister find out about his portal and go after him. They get involved in a war between the giant rebellion against the government. The technology they use looks like medieval and steampunk mixed. I do not remember.

In the end there's a big battle between the two parties, the government army has zeppelin and the rebellion wins thanks to the father and his family's help, because they helped to set up traps on the battlefield, which is some kind of forest with giant luminescent mushrooms and trees that are very very tall.

Comment: One of these; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-animated_films?

Comment: This question got retagged with [tag:anime] which usually refers to Japanese animation. However, could you describe more, like if the characters look like Japanese, or the language used in the movie? How about the races? Are all of them human? Where did you watch it?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214524/animated-movie-about-space-farmers-and-big-blue-aliens-that-had-more-then-one-ey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you or anyone else are still searching for this film, it's called [*Thru the Moebius Strip*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thru_the_Moebius_Strip) (2015).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0267024/):

> Physicist Simon Weir invents a portal that can in theory take people to unimaginably distant locations millions of light years away. He tests the portal and never returns. Everyone believe he's dead and the portal is forgotten. His son Jac however does not believe this. When he's 14, he finds his father's portal and decides to go after his dad. He emerges on a strange alien planet of giants, who follow a code of honor similar to Earth's medieval chivalry. Jac meets some friendly locals and finds out that his father is still alive, but imprisoned. The aliens make no distinction between technology and magic, so Jac plans to use this to rescue his dad. What he doesn't realize is that stakes are much hire than that.